# Display date in SSRS report header when t-sql resultset is empty

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a simple SSRS report that's composed of two section: the details section and the header section. The header has a title and the detail has the stored procedure resultset.

The report calls stored procedure dbo.usp_GetChanges that looks something like this:

```
create procedure dbo.usp_GetChanges
as 

declare @Date int

select top 1 @Date = datekey
from DatesProcessed order by DatesProcessedid desc

select RunDate, OldName, NewName from EmployeeLog
where RunDate = @Date
```

If the last rundate is 20150215, then the result looks like this:

```
20150215    Joe    John
20150215    Mary   Marie
20150215    Bob    Bobo
```

For the SSRS header, I use the SP's resultset to populate the title. So the title for that day's report is: *Changes for 20150215*

But let's say that at the moment the report's run, no changes were made, so the SP doesn't return anything. Is is possible to return @Date with that same stored procedure?

I know there are several ways to fix the issue (ie. subreports, another SP, etc); I'm looking for a solution that can be integrated into this stored procedure.

I was considering adding an OUTPUT variable to the SP (ie. `@Date datetime OUTPUT`) but SSRS interprets that as an input parameter. I tried hiding it in SSRS, but it asks me for the parameter value, even though it's not used for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the stored procedure check if the select is returning rows. If so return the selected rows otherwise select the date.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
  select RunDate, OldName, NewName from EmployeeLog
  where RunDate = @Date)
BEGIN
  select @Date RunDate
END
ELSE
  select RunDate, OldName, NewName from EmployeeLog
  where RunDate = @Date)
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Can IF NOT EXISTS be used with a common table expression (CTE)?

Comment: You can use it in FROM clause `from cte`. but if you mean declare a CTE inside IF NOT EXISTS check [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99072/using-a-cte-in-if-exists-query)

Comment: It works more or less. It fixes the date issue in the header, but the SSRS table displays one empty row since the query technically returns _a row_. But it's a good-enough solution.

Comment: If my answer was helpful you can up-vote it or select it as correct answer if so.